# selenium - how to click on a link based on its text using css instead of xpath and without using the contains operator?

Tags: css, xpath, selenium

I try to use css locators over xpath when I can.

I have the following xpath locator that I would like to change to css:

```
//table[@id='service_schedule_sets']//a[text()='OptimalTest']
```

I would like to use a css locator.  I wish to avoid using contains as there are support issues in later versions of css (i.e. `contains` was removed from css2 and css3 (css2 removal was a very last minute thing) that selenium covers up but I would like to avoid.

I am trying:

```
css=table#service_schedule_sets a[.='OptimalTest')
```

but it doesn't find the element.

The HTML is:

```
<td>
  <a href="service_schedule_sets/905">OptimalTest</a>
</td>
```

Notes:

I want to use the text in the link ('OptimalTest') not the href.
I do not want to use link=OptimalTest approach as it is not specific enough.

Comment: There is no such way I am afraid. Perhaps slap some ID's on it instead, but in terms of your original question it is not possible. XPath is the only way to *reliably* search via text. The backup plan could be to use jQuery, but this is bad simply because it's not a *standard*...that is to say you will need to ensure each and every page has jQuery loaded up on it, which isn't wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS selectors do not support node selection based on their text content.

Actually there was a suggestion for a pseudo class `:contains` which would suit your needs, but it was [removed](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors) from CSS 3 spec.